# R: Select the maximum from a group of values to be assigned to a column

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a sample column that I have:

```
Price <- c(1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 7, 10, 6)
```

In a new column `MaxPrice`, I need to select the maximum price every seven fields. With the first 6 columns only choosing max price based `1:6, 1:5, 1:4, 1:3, 1:2, 1:2, 1:1`

Result would be as follows

```
MaxPrice 
1 (Max price between 1:1)
2 (Max price between 1:2)
5 (Max price between 1:3)
5 (Max price between 1:4)
5 (Max price between 1:5)
5 (Max price between 1:6)
7 (Max price between 1:7)
10 (Max price between 2:8)
10 (Max price between 3:9)
... (Max Price between 93:100)
```

What would be the best way to go about this in dplyr or any other package?

Comment: So the first 6 elements are `cummax()`, the rest is a rolling max with window of length 7, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `library("zoo");

Price <- c(1,2,5,3,1,4,7,10,6);
c(cummax(Price[1:6]), rollmax(Price, 7))`

Comment: Worked out perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr` and `slide()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)
library(purrr)

Price <- c(1,2,5,3,1,4,7,10,6)
df <- data.frame(Price)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(MaxPrice = slide(Price, max, .before = 7, .after = 0, .complete = F)  %>% flatten_dbl)
```

The `slide()` function compute rolling summaries of your data. Arguments `.before` and `.after` set the window. The `.complete=F` argument assures that it uses the data you have when the window is not complete.

The `slide()` function was returning a list, within the dataframe, if numeric values are needed you can use `flatten_dbl` to convert it to a numeric variable (with help from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012101/how-to-stop-slide-function-from-compute-a-numeric-vector-into-a-list/65012126#65012126)) .