# How to stop slide() function from compute a numeric vector into a list?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` of one column:

```
Price <- c(1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 7, 10, 6)
df <- data.frame(Price)
```

I want to calculate the maximum value of each seven numbers, resulting in:

```
df$MaxPrice <- c(1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 10, 10)
```

However, when I try to compute this new column with `mutate()` and `slide()`, it returns me a list inside the dataframe, instead of a numeric variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(MaxPrice = slide(Price, max, .before = 7, .after = 0, .complete = F))
```

Why is this happening, and how to make `slide()` return a numeric variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the default method calls for the `list` output.   According to `?slide`

> vec_ptype(slide(.x)) == list()

and the description for `.ptype` is

> .ptype - [vector(0) / NULL]

> A prototype corresponding to the type of the output.

> If NULL, the default, the output type is determined by computing the common type across the results of the calls to .f.

> If supplied, the result of each call to .f will be cast to that type, and the final output will have that type.

> If getOption("vctrs.no_guessing") is TRUE, the .ptype must be supplied. This is a way to make production code demand fixed types.

In essence based on the source code (below), it is by default returning a `list` and there seems to be no option to prevent that unless we opt for specific methods described i.e. `_vec` or `_dbl`

Either we could `flatten`

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)
library(purrr)
out <- df %>% 
    mutate(MaxPrice = slide(Price, max, .before = 7, .after = 0,
       .complete = FALSE) %>% flatten_dbl) 

str(out)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Price   : num  1 2 5 3 1 4 7 10 6
# $ MaxPrice: num  1 2 5 5 5 5 7 10 10
```

---

Or use the type specific method i.e. `slide_dbl`

```
out <- df %>% 
    mutate(MaxPrice = slide_dbl(Price, max, .before = 7, .after = 0,
       .complete = FALSE) )

str(out)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Price   : num  1 2 5 3 1 4 7 10 6
# $ MaxPrice: num  1 2 5 5 5 5 7 10 10
```

---

If we check the source code of `slide`, it calls `slide_impl` and it assumes that `.ptype` as `list` and there is no option to pass that info in `slide`

```
slide
function (.x, .f, ..., .before = 0L, .after = 0L, .step = 1L, 
    .complete = FALSE) 
{
    slide_impl(.x, .f, ..., .before = .before, .after = .after, 
        .step = .step, .complete = .complete, .ptype = list(), 
        .constrain = FALSE, .atomic = FALSE)
}
```

Now, compare that with the `_dbl` method

```
slide_dbl
function (.x, .f, ..., .before = 0L, .after = 0L, .step = 1L, 
    .complete = FALSE) 
{
    slide_vec_direct(.x, .f, ..., .before = .before, .after = .after, 
        .step = .step, .complete = .complete, .ptype = double())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However I can only accept it in 10 minutes. Do you know why did it happen that way? I mean, slide() does not always return lists, does it?

Comment: @Escurisse It is related to the source code.  I updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `cummax` function in base R:

```
Price <- c(1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 7, 10, 6)
cummax(Price)
[1]  1  2  5  5  5  5  7 10 10
```

For multi-vector case.  Load data vector to a matrix and apply cummax to the columns.  Generates a matrix of cummax vectors for follow on treatment:

```
    Prices <- sample(1:10, 70, replace = TRUE) # dummy data
     [1] 10  1  1  9  9  6  6  9  7  3  6  4 10  4  8  6  6  9  2  1  6  4  7 10  1  6  5  2  7  7  4  6  7  7  7
    [36]  2  8  5  4  8  4  7  7  1  7  5  9  6  7  3 10  5 10  1  2  5  1  1  8  5  8  8  6  8  6  8 10  4  8  8
    matPrices <- matrix(Prices, ncol = 10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10    9    8    4    7    2    7    3    1     8
[2,]    1    7    6    7    7    8    1   10    1     6
[3,]    1    3    6   10    4    5    7    5    8     8
[4,]    9    6    9    1    6    4    5   10    5    10
[5,]    9    4    2    6    7    8    9    1    8     4
[6,]    6   10    1    5    7    4    6    2    8     8
[7,]    6    4    6    2    7    7    7    5    6     8
    matcummax <- apply(matPrices, 2, cummax)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10    9    8    4    7    2    7    3    1     8
[2,]   10    9    8    7    7    8    7   10    1     8
[3,]   10    9    8   10    7    8    7   10    8     8
[4,]   10    9    9   10    7    8    7   10    8    10
[5,]   10    9    9   10    7    8    9   10    8    10
[6,]   10   10    9   10    7    8    9   10    8    10
[7,]   10   10    9   10    7    8    9   10    8    10
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. It worked for the sample data that I provided. However, as I want to "calculate the maximum value of each seven numbers", then this solution would not be extensible to a larger dataframe, right?

Comment: The `cummax` function is extensible to any length.  What else are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not make myself clear. I was trying to get the max of every group of seven consecutives values of price. I imagine that there is also a valid and good solution for this problem with `cummax`. This may be also useful for me and other users to learn about. But my question was specifically addressing the behavior of `slide()` function in solving my problem.

Comment: OK.  I subscribe to the Einstein adage when coding, "Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler"  Multi cummax example a updated answer.

Comment: You are right, no doubt. Thanks for your time and answer (+1). Will this code compute the max of every group of 7 values, despite of the column I apply it to?

Comment: If the column length is not a multiple of 7, just load the largest multiple to the matrix and do the residual less than 7 vector singly.  E.g. if `length(Prices) = 81`, then `matPrices <- matrix(Prices[1:77], ncol = 11)`  `lastPrices <- cummax(Prices[78:81])`